# Android - Save Notifications data in Shared Preferences

Tags: android, push-notification

I am developing an Android App, I using firebase push notifications, I want **onMessageReceived()** should save the notifications data into the shared preferences, so that in future I'll show a list view where user will be able to see all the notifications.

Issue: My issue is sometimesAPP is saving the notification to sharedPrefs and sometimes not, And If i receive notification in background then it never saves to shared prefs.

I did the following implementation:

```
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){

        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: Printing Message details: ");
        Log.d(TAG, "Title: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Map<String, String> msgData = remoteMessage.getData();
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }



        Notification notification;
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String msg = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        notification = new Notification(title, msg);
        ArrayList<Notification> notificationsList = AppData.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getNotifications();
        notificationsList.add(notification);
        AppData.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setNotifications(notificationsList);


        generateNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getImageUrl());
}
```

Notification.java

```
public class Notification {
    String msgTitle;
    String msgBody;
    String imageURL;
    String time;
    Boolean read = false;

    public Notification(String msgTitle, String msgBody) {
        this.msgTitle = msgTitle;
        this.msgBody = msgBody;
    }

}
```

AppData is a singleton class, which is saving data in shared preferences.

AppData method I'am using:

```
public ArrayList<Notification> getNotifications() {
    SharedPrefrences.init(context);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = SharedPrefrences.read(Constants.E_NOTIFICATIONS, "");
    if(json == "") return null;
    Notification[] notifications = gson.fromJson(json, Notification[].class);
    ArrayList<Notification> notificationArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    notificationArrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(notifications));
    return notificationArrayList;
}

public void setNotifications(ArrayList<Notification> notifications) {
    this.notifications = notifications;
    SharedPrefrences.init(context);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(notifications);
    SharedPrefrences.write(Constants.E_NOTIFICATIONS, json);
}
```

Comment: You are using notification payload, that is why onMessageReceived is not being called when the app is in background. Use only data payload, see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845174/9854554

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56987273/3522570 there are some options(or) to get data on message received .. Try to use this while app is background.. for sure this will save your day

Comment: @NareshNK data payload is always coming null.

Comment: @GaneshPokale not useful!

Comment: If you are sending notification from firebase console, try using postman : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55795189/9854554

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES, @NareshNK. Your comments helped me in finding the exact solution.
The problems were,

- I was sending notification using firebase notification payload & same I trying to read.

When I start sending the messages with data json. I start getting the response in data payload, & my problem resolved.

[Official FCM Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)